# How can I add dependencies to kotlinCompilerClasspath?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I am using the kotlin-gradle-plugin, configuring it as follows in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.2.RELEASE'
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.11'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}"
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
```

When I run `gradle dependencies` I get the following kotlinCompilerClasspath among other things:

```
kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.11
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.11
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.11
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.11 (*)
```

When I disabled transitive dependencies in my build.gradle as follows:

```
configurations {
    all {
        transitive = false
        resolutionStrategy {
            // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
            // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
            failOnVersionConflict()
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I run `gradle dependencies` I get the following kotlinCompilerClasspath

```
kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.11
```

How can I add dependencies to the above kotlinCompilerClasspath while still using transitive = false configuration?

For example, I have tried adding the dependency `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib` to the regular dependencies block and to the buildscript block but still the above kotlinCompilerClasspath does not change.

**Gradle version**

```
gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-10 23:05:02 UTC
Revision:     3c9abb645fb83932c44e8610642393ad62116807

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.1
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.2 x86_64
```

**UPDATE**

As recommended by hotkey below, I filtered out kotlin from the configuration, as follows.

```
configurations {
    matching { !it.name.toLowerCase().contains('kotlin') }.all {
        transitive = false
        resolutionStrategy {
            // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
            // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
            failOnVersionConflict()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to disable transitive dependencies for the `kotlinCompilerClasspath` configuration in the first place, the Kotlin Gradle plugin expects that configuration to pull the transitive dependencies of the Kotlin compiler as well:

```
configurations {
    matching { it.name != 'kotlinCompilerClasspath' }.all {
        transitive = false
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

If you still want to disable transitive dependencies for all configurations, you can instead manually add those dependencies which were reported as transitive for the `kotlin-compiler-embeddable` module:

```
dependencies {
    kotlinCompilerClasspath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
    kotlinCompilerClasspath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime'
    kotlinCompilerClasspath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    kotlinCompilerClasspath 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
}
```